Pine script - consecutive bars with additional requirement
I have no idea how to solve problem with indicator. I'm trying to color bars when there's 1-5 consecutive with bodies<50% and previous bar to those 1-5 will have low below them. I can't refer to previous of 3 bars back because number of bars with bodies <50% varies...
//@version=5
indicator("Consecutive Candles Coloring", overlay=true)

// Define the number of consecutive candles to check
consecutiveCandles = input(5, "Consecutive Candles", minval=1, maxval=5)

var arr_candles array.new_float()

// Check if the candle meets the conditions
checkConditions(candle) =>
    // Cond1: Body size < 50%
    bodySize = math.abs(open - close)
    condition1 = bodySize < 0.5 * math.abs(high - low) ? array.push(arr_candles,low) : array.clear(arr_candles)

    // Cond2: number of consecutive candles with 50% body is btwn 1-5
    BaseCount = math.sum(BaseSize ? 1 : 0, 5)
    condition2 = BaseCount >= 1 and BaseCount <= 5 ? ta.lowest(math.round(BaseCount)) : na

    // Cond3: Lowest low of consecutive candles higher than previous bar low
    condition3 = ??? < condition2

    all_cond = condition1 and condition2 and condition3
    
for i=0 to bar_index

barcolor(all_cond ? color.red : na)

